# OptionMenu в ActionBar на устройствах с кнопкой "меню опций"

Tags: java, android, android-menu

В приложении должен быть `ActionBar`. Использую удобную библиотеку `android-support-v7-appcompat`.
Хотелось бы ещё добавить кнопку `OptionMenu` в `ActionBar` на тех устройствах, на которых меню опций вызывает специальной кнопкой. Кто-то ведь уже такое реализовывал. Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом?

Мало балов. Пока не могу сама отвечать на свои вопросы.
Ответ:

```
 try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if(menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Ignore
}
```

кусок кода засунуть в метод onCreate() вашей Activity. Пишут, что решение временное. Но всё же решение.

Comment: уточню, хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выпадал список вариантов выбора под actionbar. вобщем точь-в-точь чтобы всё было одинаковое

Answer (score 2):

добавляем в папку res/menu xml файл с разметкой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >

<!--элмент который будет показываться в меню, если есть место-->
    <item android:id="@+id/searchMenu"
          android:title="Поиск"
          android:icon="@drawable/head_search"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
            />

<!--Элементы которые будут в выпадабщем меню с трея точками-->
    <item android:id="@+id/faqMenuItem"
          android:title="FAQ"
          android:showAsAction="never"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
            />

    <item android:id="@+id/settingsMenuItem"
          android:title="Settings"
          android:showAsAction="never"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
            />

</menu>
```

Затем в активити/фрагменте   при создании меню

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu_file_name, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**UPD:**  
Обработка нажатий

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item)
    {
        final int itemId = item.getItemId();
      //это то, что указано в  android:id="@+id/faqMenuItem"
    }
```

Comment: как кнопку в экшнбар добавлять понятно. а где и как обработать её нажатие.

Comment: @Nina_slon обновил ответ

Comment: это тоже ясно :) как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на   searchMenu - выпадал список? и где?

Comment: >> добавляем в папку res/menu xml файл с разметкой   
Я же описал все

Comment: я же говорю, что для телефонов с аппаратной кнопкой необходимо решение. короче, это нефига не решение или оно не работает так как вы описали. уж такой простой код я и сама напишу ;)

Answer (score 1):

Два дня мучился. Перерыл не мало страниц и нашел решение. Суть проблемы. Я на проекте использовал Fragment. Что это и с чем едят можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxEi_I3tv2k&list=LLUC6kN4ax2EoKFR9VHwcI5g&index=1)
Проблема заключалась в отсутствии меню, точнее небыло возможности управлять меню из fragment-а. Что я сделал.
1. Меню

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item_car_id"
        android:title="@string/carage_item_view"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

2. Функция создания меню

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
     // Inflate the menu
     getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Чтоб меню появилось на фрагменте в onCreate нужно вызвать фнкцию setHasOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle save){
    super.onCreate(save);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Ну и само собой слушатель событий меню

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_car_id:
                    Log.i("LOG_DEV", "action_settings = click" + item);
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Виталий, а это у вас новый вопрос или ответ на этот? Я что-то не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Сам долго с этим мучился. Сделал так:

1) Создаём файл menu.xml в папке "res/menu".

2) В файле пишем следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

**Главное** тут - объявление пространства имён "app" в корневом тэге `<menu>` (xmlns:**app**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto") и добавление в тэг `<item/>` строки (**app**:showAsAction="never")
Также я добавил иконку "ic_action_overflow_ligth" в папку "res/drawable", кою скачал отсюда: [Официальный сборник иконок для ActionBar от Гугла](https://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip)

3) В вашей Activity пишем:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.action_settings:
                 //Делаем то, что нам нужно (Вызываем фрагмент/ активити настроек)
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

В итоге должна отображаться иконка настроек с тремя точками на всех девайсах (и с хардверной кнопкой настроек и без неё).

Comment: подскажите, а как скрыть эту кнопку на устройства, где нет аппаратной кнопки меню? т.е. у меня получается 2 кнопки, которые выглядят одинаково и делают одно и тоже? или проще скрыть кнопку настроек?

Comment: Вот такое отличное решение нашлось http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button/11438245#11438245